# How to replace a string in a file only if the line containing it also contains a number found in another file using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

I would like to replace all instances of `target` with `replace` in the following file.csv using Bash, but only if the line containing it also contains a number found in list.txt:

file.csv:

```
1,abc,target,abc
2,abc,target,abc
3,abc,target,abc
```

list.txt:

```
1
3
```

Desired output:

```
1,abc,replace,abc
2,abc,target,abc
3,abc,replace,abc
```

I am attempting to use `sed`:

```
sed 's/target/replace' file.csv > newfile.csv
```

How can I include logic to check each line against list.txt?

Comment: Hmm.. Good that you've shown your effort with the  question. But you may search the SO first for you might see similar questions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a job suited more for `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }       # set input/output field delimiter to comma
   FNR == NR {                  # for 1st file in the arguments i.e. list.txt
      a[$1]                     # store each value of $1 in an array a
      next                      # move to next record
}
$1 in a {                       # for 1st file in the arguments i.e. file.csv
   sub(/target/, "replace", $3) # replace target by replace in 3rd column
} 1' list.txt file.csv          # print each record from 2nd file

1,abc,replace,abc
2,abc,target,abc
3,abc,replace,abc
```

#### [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/KSY2sP)

Comment: No, it seems to output the same data that was in file.csv.

Comment: Generated output is shown in in my answer, which is exactly same as your expected output.

Comment: When I run your code exactly, I get this:
1,abc,target,abc
2,abc,target,abc
3,abc,target,abc

I expect to see this:
1,abc,replace,abc
2,abc,target,abc
3,abc,replace,abc

Comment: Check if your files have DOS line endings. Also make sure sample data is exactly same as your actual data.

Comment: [Here is the working code demo of above command](http://ideone.com/KSY2sP)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a mash of [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) and `sed`.

Using `sed` to generate `sed` commands

```
$ sed 's|.*|/&/ s/target/replace/|' list.txt
/1/ s/target/replace/
/3/ s/target/replace/
```

Using `sed` output as script file

```
$ sed -f <(sed 's|.*|/&/ s/target/replace/|' list.txt) file.csv 
1,abc,replace,abc
2,abc,target,abc
3,abc,replace,abc
```

To match only at start of file, use

```
$ sed 's|.*|/^&/ s/target/replace/|' list.txt 
/^1/ s/target/replace/
/^3/ s/target/replace/
```

Or to restrict the pattern with word boundaries:

```
$ sed 's|.*|/\\b&\\b/ s/target/replace/|' list.txt 
/\b1\b/ s/target/replace/
/\b3\b/ s/target/replace/
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Ideas is similer with you!

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=1;next}a[$1]{$3="replace"}1' OFS="," list.txt file.cvs
```

Comment: No, this will set all the  `$3` to `replace`. OP wants to replace only `target` to `replace`.

Comment: I think it ‘s rigth,please test it!